# Using CSS to format HTML page - wont display correctly on live site

Tags: html, css

New to CSS and HTML. I am using a stylesheet to format some text on an HTML page - essentially centring the text and images so they feat neatly in the middle of the page. I wanted the text to fit into the same column of space that the image occupies so I am left with a neat column of text and images...

The code seems to work correctly when I preview it in brackets (through Chrome). However when i upload the code to the server, the website does not format correctly:

In chrome the formatting does not appear to have been applied at all.
In Explorer the width of the text column is wider than the image, so the text is not "flush" with the image.
In Safari it seems to work properly.

The website is: www.spoonsoflondon.com if anyone wants to see how they render differently!

Can anyone help? The Stylesheet code is below:

```
img{
display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

body{
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

p{
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Can you write the HTML too? The CSS seems to be correct. Have you made sure you are linking to the stylesheet properly? Not correct relative paths are most likely to be the problem here.

Comment: I went to your site and everything seems to be rigth. Did you fix it or you still need some help?

Comment: Seems OK to me. You should probably get your HTML on here too.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin: 0 auto; for block elements and text-align: center; for headers...

```
h1, h2, h3
{ 
    text-align: center; 
}

p
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and then for your header tag to match the rest:

```
header
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
}
```

If you've already made these changes and uploaded them, confirming that they were saved, try refreshing your cache with CTRL + F5 to refresh the css updates.

Answer (score 0):

Looked like it worked fine for me in Chrome and Microsoft Edge (Win 10 IE). If you changed your stylesheet on the server, but it's not showing correctly in the browser, your browser may be using a cached version of the stylesheet.

In Chrome, **CTRL+SHIFT+i** > click on **Network** > Check **Disable Cache** > Reload the page. If that fixes it, then the site is fine and your cache is invalid.

**Solution:**

You can change the href in `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` to `href="style.css?1"` so the new file will be delivered regardless of previously set cache-headers. (thus, anyone who had previously cached `style.css` will now get the new file.)

**Note:**
On your page, you have `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`, which is using a relative path for `style.css`, so if you load the page `www.spoonsoflondon.com/some_dir/some_other_file.html`, then the stylesheet loaded would be `www.spoonsoflondon.com/some_dir/style.css`. You should use an absolute path like `href="/style.css"`, or for the sake of organization, `href="/cssFiles/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your page in both safari, chrome and firefox, and it displays he same. I think you need to specify centering the information in the body using

```
body{
    text-align:center
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You can also try wrapping the contents in <div> or <span> to preserve the look, while the text-align:center will only apply to the <div>